# Is it preferred to shut down or to put my Ubuntu machine to sleep, on daily manner?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate

In terms of product lifetime, and for the long run,is it preferred to shut down or put to sleep a Ubuntu machine daily?

Comment: there are different ways to put a sleep on a linux machine. suspend-to-ram and -to-disk. And you can even pull the power chord, as a variation. Otherwise: interesting Q, also energy saving wise.

Comment: I mean: after a normal shutdown you can additionally detach the electric cable, to avoid the ~0.7 W standby.

Answer (score 4):

I am glad Murphy already answered. He gives a good overview.

The Q is very practical and concerns almost every one with a "PC" i.e. a system he owns and runs. And that he puts to sleep before he (or she) goes to bed herselves.

I leave out the case of laptop - there it is 90% about (main) battery.

I first list the Watt consumed on a 28 Watt thermal design power **mini-pc**. I have it plugged in to a watt-o-meter (constantly, because it shows "system load" very well -- I have to measure it also, with a second one...).

```
3.5 W "idle" normal firefox load when "active": 4 to 6 W, but VERY variable  
2.7 W "X sleep", auto after 5 min. Standbies also the monitor (10W to 0.0)
1.1 W suspend-to-RAM
0.7 W Off
0.0 W detached from 19V-converter cable
```

And compare: my (cheap) radio-alarm-clock uses 2.2W when it is "off".

Btw. one reason I have my distro is because *others* had 5.5W. A kernel panic is 10W, as is BIOS.

Because suspend-to-ram is so fast, and less than half a watt more than "Off", I use it *on a daily basis*. There is a special RAM state for it, RAM needs a minimum current to keep the bits alive. I guess this does not harm at all.

I am confident my system can handle anything *between* 3 years without power and three years constantly over 30W.

Hibernating is a good compromise, but if you misconfigure (or use on a hourly basis) it might use the disk too much.

Maybe "product lifetime" is not the first concern. Depending on your "machine", and it's parts, it could matter a bit or not.

I have no problem to find an good solution with linux for me, for energy consumption and hopefully also product lifetime. I like to decide every night, and then I mostly go:

Ctrl-R, "mem"
echo mem > /sys/power/state

Like I do on a *hourly* basis.

---

I tried changing this, with different kernels, and different results.

```
]# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
s2idle [deep]
```

So yes, the machine has different states, and linux has different ways to control it.

Answer (score 3):

A detailed explanation [can for instance be found here](https://www.howtogeek.com/128507/htg-explains-should-you-shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-laptop/).

A quick summary:

- Suspend to RAM (this is usually meant when people say "sleep") will consume some power, but bring your system quickly back to life. If it loses power (because the battery is finally drained, or you flip the switch of your desktop system), you'll loose the saved state and it has to boot.
- Suspend to Disk ("hibernate") will take longer both saving and resuming, but you won't lose the saved state when the power is lost; the system is powered off anyhow.
- Power down ("halt") will shut down your operating system completely, and it has to be booted after power on. This takes the most time, but regarding power consumption it's like hibernating.

For practical reasons I usually hibernate my systems (Laptop and PC) when I leave them alone, and only use sleep when I intend to resume my work soon. You could use the hybrid variant explained in the link if supported by your system, but it isn't good for the lifespan of your battery if it's constantly drained and charged in alternation. Regarding the wear on SSDs when suspending to disk, IMHO this can be neglected with today's hardware and usual use cases (hibernating up to two or three times a day on average).

This isn't specific to any operating system or distribution, provided it supports your hardware reliably. That should be standard today, but isn't necessarily, especially with cheap hardware, as there are still many components involved that must play well together.

Answer (score 1):

for small breaks use `sleep` mode
for long breaks use `hibernate` mode, saves battery
and use `poweroff` mode in the night

Answer (score -1):

With a good SSD in the machine, it boots so fast that you don't need to put your computer to sleep anymore to save time.